ffmpeg extremely slow HEVC without any major changes in the system
I have the same dedicated NAS machine for a while now with AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core it's not the strongest but more than enough for my home NAS usage.
I also use the same machine to re-encode h264 and h265 videos to h265, mainly to change keyint values.
Something that I cannot put my finger on changed recently (in the last two weeks) without any version changes to ffmpeg and only minor updates on the OS (if any) and the ffmpeg speeds are not decreased to 1/20th or 1/100th of what it used to be.
I am struggling to check what is going wrong where, I'd appreciate any pointers for debugging this issue.
a copy paste from a recent re-encode:
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.5+1-f0c1022b6
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 8.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-6 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 16 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 4 / wpp(38 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 3 inter / 3 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : star / 57 / 4 / 5
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 50 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 40 / 8 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 1
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 5 / off / off
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-22.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rect amp rd=6 psy-rd=2.00 rdoq=2 psy-rdoq=1.00 rskip mode=1
x265 [info]: tools: signhide tmvp b-intra strong-intra-smoothing deblock sao

frame=98957 fps=0.8 q=31.8 size= 4575232kB time=00:27:31.13 bitrate=22699.7kbits/s speed=0.0127x

and here is a sample ffmpeg command about how I start the process (has not changed in years - in fact I am copy/pasting it from a script I wrote)
ffmpeg -v warning -stats -i "${working}" -c:v libx265 -c:a aac -preset veryslow -x265-params "crf=22:min-keyint=25:keyint=50" "$writeTo"


Do you have a log from before the slowdown?

unfortunately I do not

Has some sort of real time virus scan or some other access control gotten enabled?

"x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 8.3.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit"
